# tcsh: using "-c" option doesn't work for certain commands

Tags: csh, tcsh

I want to run a tcsh script from within perl. So used the -c option. However I am having problem with setenv used within the script

My script XX.tcsh has
 setenv xx dd

If I try to execute this script using
 "tcsh -c XX.tcsh"

I get the error
setenv: Command not found

inside XX.tcsh I added the line
which setenv.
The output I got was

which: no setenv in ()

However if I execute which setenv from my tcsh shell I get

setenv: shell built-in command

Could somebody help in resolving this. Not sure what I am missing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `-c`.

`tcsh XX.tcsh` shoud work.